How does service in k8s recognize different destination ports via iptables?
When apply a k8s service as below, This one service exposes two different ports for two pods.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: products
    department: sales
  ports:
  - name: port-v1
    protocol: TCP
    port: 39090
    targetPort: 9090
  - name: port-v2
    protocol: TCP
    port: 49191
    targetPort: 9191

The service will be generated with the following result
root@cp01:~# kcds hello-service
Name:                     hello-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=products,department=sales
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.101.173.15
IPs:                      10.101.173.15
Port:                     port-v1  39090/TCP
TargetPort:               9090/TCP
NodePort:                 port-v1  30725/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.189.15:9090
Port:                     port-v2  49191/TCP
TargetPort:               9191/TCP
NodePort:                 port-v2  31576/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.189.15:9191
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>


Then I found that kube-proxy will add the following rule to the iptables NAT table
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
......
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.101.173.15/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v1 cluster IP" -j KUBE-SVC-R4PDB35TUPNR4CEW  # No dest port as parameter
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.101.173.15/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v2 cluster IP" -j KUBE-SVC-P73F5K5MMQHXGZV7  # No dest port as parameter
......
-A KUBE-SVC-P73F5K5MMQHXGZV7 -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v2 -> 192.168.189.15:9191" -j KUBE-SEP-GZ2FT6XOW5XY6PQC
-A KUBE-SVC-R4PDB35TUPNR4CEW -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v1 -> 192.168.189.15:9090" -j KUBE-SEP-AA54JU3D4RO26WUA
......
-A KUBE-SEP-GZ2FT6XOW5XY6PQC -s 192.168.189.15/32 -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v2" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-GZ2FT6XOW5XY6PQC -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v2" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.189.15:9191
-A KUBE-SEP-AA54JU3D4RO26WUA -s 192.168.189.15/32 -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v1" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-AA54JU3D4RO26WUA -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/hello-service:port-v1" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.189.15:9090
......

What makes me feel strange is the two rules in KUBE-SERVICES, their matching parameters are exactly the same, both use -d 10.101.173.15/32 -p tcp as the matching parameter, and do not use the destination port as the basis of the difference, just the comment is different, how can you differentiate between packets that are sent to different destination addresses?
And the actual test actually matched successfully, I executed the outgoing to 39090 twice and port 49191 once with the following results
# twice
curl -L -v http://10.101.173.15:39090
curl -L -v http://10.101.173.15:39090
# once
curl -L -v http://10.101.173.15:49191

root@cp01:~# iptables -t nat -L -v -n --line-number | grep 10.101.173.15
2        2   120 KUBE-SVC-R4PDB35TUPNR4CEW  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.101.173.15        /* defau                                        lt/hello-service:port-v1 cluster IP */
3        1    60 KUBE-SVC-P73F5K5MMQHXGZV7  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.101.173.15        /* defau                                        lt/hello-service:port-v2 cluster IP */

I don't understand how the K8S does it?
According to my idea, kube-proxy achieves the underlying computer control of traffic by creating various rules in iptables, which means that any control of packets has to be done through the control mechanism of iptables, but what's the deal with the above phenomenon? iptables doesn't seem to be able to control the forwarding of packets through the contents of the comments, and K8S should not interfere with the iptables mechanism in this way.
I'm really confused, please help me out!

Kubernetes uses the combination of IP and port to route traffic to the correct backend pods. The comments in the ip tables rules are for human readability and do not affect the actual routing logic. The actual differentiation is done based on the destination IP and port specified in the rules and refer this blog also

Thanks, I read this blog and this blog also mentions multiple backends, but I'm still not sure how K8S differentiates ports in iptables

When you create a Kubernetes service that exposes multiple ports, Kubernetes sets up rules for each port. IPtables operates by organizing traffic filtering into tables, chains, and rules. When kube-proxy is used in iptables mode, routing requests to services continues to work for existing services even when the kube-proxy process dies on the node Kube-proxy binds and listens to all ports allocated as NodePorts to ensure these ports stay reserved and no other processes can use them.

After further research I realized that it's not the iptables rule that differentiates the packets, but the ingress control pod that gets the packets and does the differentiating process
